# Contar cuantas veces se repite una palabra especifica

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void vocales ();

int main ()  {

char vec [250];
printf ("Ingrese una palabra cualquiera (Maximo 250 caracteres):\n");
gets(vec);

vocales();



}



void vocales () {

char vec [250];

int i;
int contA=0;
int contE=0;
int contI=0;
int contO=0;
int contU=0;


for (i=0;i<250;i++) {

    if (vec[i] == 'a' || vec[i] == 'A'){

        contA++;

    } else

    if (vec[i] == 'e' || vec[i] == 'E') {

        contE++;

    } else

    if (vec[i] == 'i' || vec[i] == 'I'){

        contI++;

    } else

    if (vec[i] == 'o' || vec[i] == 'O') {

        contO++;

    }  else

    if (vec[i] == 'u'  || vec[i] == 'U') {

        contU++;

    } 

}


printf ("Tiene: %d veces la letra A\n",contA);
printf ("Tiene: %d veces la letra E\n",contE);
printf ("Tiene: %d veces la letra I\n",contI);
printf ("Tiene: %d veces la letra O\n",contO);
printf ("Tiene: %d veces la letra U\n",contU);

}
```

Realizar un programa que permita ingresar una frase (considere una cadena de caracteres de 250 posiciones) y luego la analice para determinar:
a) Cuantas veces se repiten las vocales.
b) Cuantas palabras "HOLA" contiene el texto.

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de imprimir la cantidad correcta de vocales, ademas no se me ocurre como implementar una función en la que reconozca la palabra "hola". ¿Alguien me podría dar alguna sugerencia a la hora de crearlo? Porque la verdad es que no se me ocurre.

Comment: fijate que definis dos vec distintos... uno en main y otro en la funcion vocales... la funcion vocales deberia recibir el vec que cargaste en el main.. y luego... usa una funcion tipo strcomp para saber si esta o no... empeza por ahi, pero seguro algun experto te da una respuesta mejor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, no te imprime los contadores de letras porque usas variables distintas. El array en el que llenas la cadena en la función main es diferente al que defines dentro de la función vocales. Así que en la función vocales el vector vec tiene a saber qué contenido (dado que no lo inicializas).

Define char vec[250] fuera del main y eliminalo de la función vocales.

Para contar las veces que aparece una palabra concreta podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
char szPrueba[] = "HOLAESTO ES HOLA PRUEBA HOLAHOLA    HOLA ";
char szCadenaABuscar[] = "HOLA";
size_t tamCadenaABuscar = strlen( szCadenaABuscar);

bool bContinue = true;
int nContador = 0;
char * lpIterator = szPrueba;

while( bContinue) {
    char * lpTemp = strstr( lpIterator, szCadenaABuscar);

    if( lpTemp != NULL) {
        nContador++;
        lpIterator = lpTemp + tamCadenaABuscar;
    } else
        bContinue = false;

}
```

szPrueba es la cadena origen en la que buscar, que me he inventado para la prueba, y szCadenaABuscar es la cadena de la que se quiere contar el número de ocurrencias en szPrueba. En cada vuelta del bucle while vas buscando (con strstr) la cadena a buscar. Esto te retorna el puntero donde está la primera ocurrencia o NULL si no existe. Si existe, incrementas el contador de veces encontrada, e incrementas el puntero saltándote la palabra, para que siga buscando en el resto de la cadena. El bucle termina cuando strstr retorna NULL porque o ha terminado la cadena szPrueba y no hay nada más, o hay más, pero no encuentra la palabra a buscar en lo que queda de szPrueba.